# Implement UIPickerViewDataSource in protocol extension

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

Is there any way to write a protocol extension in swift that implements another protocol, like UIPickerViewDataSource? I'd like to create a sort of mixin for the UIPickerViewDataSource (notice the 2 methods in MyProtocol are the required methods in UIPickerViewDataSource)  For example:

```
protocol MyProtocol: UIPickerViewDataSource {
  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
}

extension MyProtocol {
  func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
  func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView,
numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
  }
}
```

Then I would add the protocol to my class:

```
class MyClass: MyProtocol, UIPickerViewDataSource {}
```

Seems like it should work but it keeps telling me that my class does not conform to protocol UIPickerViewDataSource. Is this kind of thing not possible?

Comment: have you alredy implemented all methods of the UIPickerViewDataSource protocol?, your logic makes sense but you need to implemente both the methods of your protocol and the methods of UIPickerViewDataSourceprotocol

Comment: Yeah I implemented them in the protocol extension, so technically they should be implemented by MyClass. The methods in MyProtocol are the same as the methods in UIPickerViewDataSource. I'm basically trying to create a mixin for the UIPickerViewDataSource @YeisGallegos